# paypal payments pro direct payment check if successful

Tags: php, paypal

hey guys was hoping you could help me out.

I cant seem to find any proper reference or documentation for their direct payments api and variables so I am asking here now.

I am doing direct payment for the first time and according to their integration guide, the payment status should be "successful" but this is the response I am getting (i.e i do  `print_r($doDirectPaymentResponse);`  where the variable comes from

`$doDirectPaymentResponse = $paypalService->DoDirectPayment($doDirectPaymentReq,$credential_object);`
)

```
DoDirectPaymentResponseType Object
(
    [Amount] => BasicAmountType Object
        (
            [currencyID] => USD
            [value] => 12.00
        )

    [AVSCode] => X
    [CVV2Code] => M
    [TransactionID] => 9H515811FE178263Y
    [PendingReason] => 
    [PaymentStatus] => 
    [FMFDetails] => 
    [ThreeDSecureResponse] => 
    [PaymentAdviceCode] => 
    [Timestamp] => 2013-02-01T15:56:31Z
    [Ack] => Success
    [CorrelationID] => a0a240936bf65
    [Errors] => 
    [Version] => 94.0
    [Build] => 5060305
)
```

also, what exactly does the ack field tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ack` is the field you want to pay attention to.  If it's `Success` or `SuccessWithWarning`, the payment went through successfully, and `TransactionID` has your transaction ID.  If it's `Failure` or `FailureWithWarning`, it didn't go through.